# Unable to make Retrofit2 interface generic for all Models

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 in my app and it works really fine, but i am trying to use a single interface for all kind of GET method requests by passing a dynamic model. When i try it using following code, it gives error at runtime

```
public interface LoadDataServiceTest<T> {
        @GET
        Call<T> getModel(@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class ModelTest<T> {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("users")
    private T data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

But when i create service as following, then i get error. How can i resolve it and what is the best approach to achieve this goal.

```
LoadDataServiceTest<ModelTest<JsonArray>> service = retrofit.create((Class<LoadDataServiceTest<ModelTest<JsonArray>>>) (Class<?>) APIs.LoadDataServiceTest.class);
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("user_id",userId);
        Call<ModelTest<JsonArray>> call = service.getModel(APIs.GET_USERS, parameters);
```

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.iu.colgatepalmolive, PID: 16808
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.iu.colgatepalmolive/com.iu.hfl_ccp.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method return type must not
>   include a type variable or wildcard: retrofit2.Call
>                                                                                for method LoadDataServiceTest.getModel
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method return type must
>   not include a type variable or wildcard: retrofit2.Call
>                                                                                for method LoadDataServiceTest.getModel
>                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:711)
>                                                                                at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:224)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:160)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>                                                                                at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
>                                                                                at $Proxy5.getModel(Unknown Source)

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2012)

Comment: Inshort, it isn't possible. Thanks for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I use following approach.
At first I have implemented custom Call

```
public class ProxyConvertCall<Tin,Tout> implements Call<Tout> {
    Converter<Tin,Tout> converter;
    Call<Tin> innerCall;

    public ProxyConvertCall(Call<Tin> jcall, Converter<Tin,Tout> converter){
        this.innerCall = jcall;
        this.converter = converter;
        }

    @Override
    public Response<Tout> execute() throws IOException {
        Response<Tin> response = innerCall.execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            return Response.success(converter.Convert(response.body()),response.raw());
        }
        else return Response.error(response.code(), response.errorBody());
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(final Callback<Tout> callback) {
        final Call<Tout> self = this;
        this.innerCall.enqueue(new Callback<Tin>() {  
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Tin> call, Response<Tin> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    callback.onResponse(self, Response.success(converter.Convert(response.body()), response.raw()));
                }
                else callback.onResponse(self, Response.error(response.code(), response.errorBody()));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Tin> call, Throwable t) {
                callback.onFailure(self,t);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExecuted() {
        return innerCall.isExecuted();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        innerCall.cancel();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCanceled() {
        return innerCall.isCanceled();
    }

    @Override
    public Call<Tout> clone() {
        return new ProxyConvertCall<>(innerCall,converter);
    }

    @Override
    public Request request() {
        return innerCall.request();
    }
}
```

It adapts `Call<Tin>` to `Call<Tou>` using a converter.

```
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface Converter<Tin, Tout> {
    public Tout Convert(Tin in);
}
```

For your service you must create service interface, that return JsonObject for single object and JsonArray for arrays

```
  public interface LoadDataServiceTest {
     @GET
     public Call<JsonObject> getModelTest(@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);

     @GET
     public Call<JsonObject> getModel(@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);

     @GET
     public Call<JsonArray> getModels(@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);


}
```

Then wrap it with generic class, with converters from JsonElement to any Type `<T>` and `ModelTest<T>`:

```
   public class LoadDataServiceTestGeneric<T> {
     Converter<JsonObject,ModelTest<T>> fromJsonObjectToModelTest;
     Converter<JsonObject,T> fromJsonObject;
     Converter<JsonArray,List<T>> fromJsonArray;
     LoadDataServiceTest service;

    public LoadDataServiceTestGeneric(Class<T> classOfT, LoadDataServiceTest service){  
        this.service = service;
        Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().create();
        GenericListType<T> genericListTypeOfT = new GenericListType<T>(classOfT);
        fromJsonObject = (t)->gson.fromJson(t,classOfT);
        fromJsonArray =(t)->gson.fromJson(t,genericListTypeOfT);
    }
    public Call<ModelTest<T>> getModelTest(String url, Map<String, String> options){ 
        return new ProxyConvertCall<>(service.getModelTest(url, options), fromJsonObjectToModelTest);
    }

    public Call<T> getModel(String url, Map<String, String> options){ 
        return new ProxyConvertCall<>(service.getModel(url, options), fromJsonObject);
    }

    Call<List<T>> getModels(String url, Map<String, String> options){ 
        return new ProxyConvertCall<>(service.getModels(url, options), fromJsonArray);
    }

}
```

GenericListType is ParameterizedType. It is used for passing type parameter to gson for `List<T>`

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericListType<T> implements ParameterizedType {

    private Type wrapped;

    public GenericListType(Type wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {wrapped};
    }

    public Type getRawType() {
        return  List.class;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

ModelTestType is ParameterizedType. It is used for passing type parameter to gson for `ModelTestType<T>`

```
public class ModelTestType  implements ParameterizedType {

        private Type wrapped;

        public ModelTestType(Type wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[] {wrapped};
        }

        public Type getRawType() {
            return  ModelTest.class;
        }

        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Then you can instantiate LoadDataServiceTestGeneric with type you want.